# What is the actual drop rate for crates?

Tags: rocket-league

Back when I was in Rookie/Semi Pro I was receiving a crate every few games. Now - top end of Pro - I might get a crate in 5 hours. Some friends say that leaving the game open for a while after finishing a match will increase your rate, but I haven't seen any proof of that. I get Uncommons fairly often after this most recent update, but have only received one Crate (CC2) since. **What factors really determine the drop rate for crates? Are there any legitimate ways to increase your chances?**

Comment: From observation, it is purely random.

Comment: It's not random. It can be measured. Nothing in the world of programming is truly random.

Comment: @Sickest: While I agree to your comment about the lack of _true_ randomness, that is not relevant to the current context. "Random" in this context means that the odds are not influenced by player actions, it doesn't address the mathematical (or even philosophical) considerations of the implementation of randomness in programming. Also, even true randomness can be measured. Anything that can be observed can be measured if you note your observations. **Predicting** and **measuring** are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trading since Championship crate 1 has been released. And I will give you a general rule of how often crates get released.

First off, Drops occur randomly. And on a weekly basis they get reset. 
The other thing you have to understand is that crates do not fall at a consistent rate during the course of a week. Some weeks you might get 2 crates, other weeks you might get 8.

But you can measure them based on the number of hours you have played the game. Whenever I used to find a new trader that has never traded crates or un-boxed crates. I would ask them how many crates they had total.

If a player started playing AFTER crates was introduced to Rocket League. The measurement would be based on the total number of hours they have played.

**10 hours per crate.**

If a person has 200 hours, they will roughly have around 20 crates. 600 hours, 60 crates. 1000 hours, 100 crates.

I've asked this question to over 200 players. The measurement is always the same. If the user had been playing long before crates was introduced, then I wouldn't take his data into account.

Answer (score 0):

3 months ago, the drop rate was 2 hours of gameplay(inside a match). It changed after an update and people no longer knows the timespan, except that it is "gameplay time" that counts.

There are some speculations about the crate drop rate using the same formula of itens drop rate: once a week you have 10 hours of gameplay where the itens may drop, or given an average match time of 7-10 minutes, your first 60 to 95 matches per week are eligible for item drops.

Answering those questions:

> What factors really determine the drop rate for crates?

- In match time (gameplay)
- Playing matches.
- Maybe there is a time cap where you no longer receive drops after it end.

> Are there any legitimate ways to increase your chances?

Only if they make an update, because this is server sided.

"Ilegitimate", only if you are friend with some dev or hack their servers.